# MySQL manipulate view data

Tags: mysql, sql, union, sql-view, cross-join

I am reading a view which gives me data like below:

```
msn       | global_device_id | meter_datetime        | interval| channel_id | active_energy_pos_t1     
==================================================================================================
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 16:45:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:00:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:15:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:30:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
....
```

The `channel_id` is `1` for each and every record. I want to manipulate it. I want to make exact `3 copies` of the above data `virtually` the `1st` data should have `channel_id` as `1` the second should have `channel_id` as `2` and the 3rd should have `channel_id` as `3` like below

```
msn       | global_device_id | meter_datetime        | interval| channel_id | active_energy_pos_t1     
==================================================================================================
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 16:45:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:00:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:15:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:30:00   | 15      | 1          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 16:45:00   | 15      | 2          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:00:00   | 15      | 2          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:15:00   | 15      | 2          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:30:00   | 15      | 2          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 16:45:00   | 15      | 3          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:00:00   | 15      | 3          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:15:00   | 15      | 3          | 72.80300
3798000021| 980021           | 2020-07-29 17:30:00   | 15      | 3          | 72.80300

....
```

The view name is `load_profile_data`.  How can I do it?

Comment: Note that queries against VIEWs in MySQL cannot utilise underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable.

Answer (score 2):

You can cross join the view with a list of fixed values:

```
select l.msn, l.global_device_id, l.meter_datetime, l.interval, c.channel_id, l.active_energy_pos_t1
from load_profile_data l
cross join (select 1 channel_id union all select 2 union all select 3) c
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a union:

```sql
SELECT msn, global_device_id, meter_datetime, `interval`, channel_id, active_energy_pos_t1
FROM load_profile_data
UNION ALL
SELECT msn, global_device_id, meter_datetime, `interval`, 2, active_energy_pos_t1
FROM load_profile_data
UNION ALL
SELECT msn, global_device_id, meter_datetime, `interval`, 3, active_energy_pos_t1
FROM load_profile_data;
```

Side note: `INTERVAL` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  I escaped in backticks in the query above, but in general you should avoid using reserved keywords to name your database objects.

Comment: the interval is ok but I want to change the `channel_id`

Comment: It's taking forever :(

Comment: UNION ALL is already more optimal than UNION.  I don't know of any way to speed up my answer, _other_ than looking at the view itself and optimizing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try union:

```
select msn , global_device_id , meter_datetime . interval, channel_id ,active_energy_pos_t1 from load_profile_data

union

select msn , global_device_id , meter_datetime . interval, channel_id +1 ,active_energy_pos_t1 from load_profile_data

union

select msn , global_device_id , meter_datetime . interval, channel_id+2 ,active_energy_pos_t1 from load_profile_data
```

Comment: It's taking too much time